# Computation of $\tilde{H}_k(\bigvee_{j = 1}^N S^n)$.

Tags: homology-cohomology, quotient-spaces

In my algebraic topology course, we state the following proposition
$$
\tilde{H}_k(\bigvee_{j = 1}^N S^n) \cong
\begin{cases}
\mathbb Z^N & \text{if } k = n,\\
0 & \text{else},
\end{cases}
$$
which should be a direct corollary of the following isomorphism
$$\tilde{H}_k(X \lor Y) \cong \tilde{H}_k(X) \oplus \tilde{H}_k(Y).$$
However, by this isomorphism, shouldn't we have
$$\tilde{H}_0(\bigvee_{j = 1}^N S^n) \cong \mathbb Z^N$$
as well ? I think my teacher made a mistake here, I just want to be sure I am not missing something.

Comment: $\bigvee_{j = 1}^N S^n$ has one path component, so $H_0\cong\mathbb Z$. Thus, the reduced homology is $\tilde{H_0}=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\tilde{H}_i$ denotes reduced homology, so $\tilde{H}_0(S^n) = 0$ and hence $$\tilde{H}_0\left(\bigvee_{j=1}^NS^n\right) = \bigoplus_{j=1}^N\tilde{H}_0(S^n) = \bigoplus_{j=1}^N0 = 0.$$

Comment: Yes my bad, thank you!